# Step by step interactive debugger for Rust?

Tags: debugging, rust

How can I debug Rust application step by step **interactively** like I'm able to do with "pry" in Ruby?

I want to be able to see and preferably change the variables in real time when I reach a break point. Is there any production ready finished project?

Comment: you can use gdb. Other than that, I'm working on a stepper for MIR (implemented on top of miri), which will allow you to debug on a kind of virtual machine.

Comment: @ker: Oh! Is miri close enough to completion already? I thought it was still in the early stages.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: there are still some things that don't work yet (e.g. function pointers), but it's slowly getting there.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4m66ja/step_by_step_interactive_debugger_for_rust/?ref=share&ref_source=link)

Comment: @Dimon it's considered Stack Overflow (and Reddit) etiquette to inform **future searchers** of other places that an answer may be found. That way, they have a better chance of getting useful information. It also potentially saves an **answerer** time, if what they were going to say is already covered in a different location.

Answer (score 105):

I find a good level of usability with [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and the [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) extension:

1. [Install VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
2. Search and install the extension [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer) from within VS Code
3. Check requisites and [setup CodeLLDB](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/wiki/Setup) for your platform. As of v1.6, no further setup should be needed.
4. Search and install the extension [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) from within VS Code
5. The LLDB Debugger added the main menu item "Run" from where the debugger can be started.
   When debugging is started for the first time, you must select the environment (the debugger): select LLDB.
6. When you select LLDB, a `launch.json` file will be opened, if not, open it, it's under `.vscode` folder
7. Your `launch.json` should look like this:

   ```js
   {
       // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
       // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
       // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "type": "lldb",
               "request": "launch",
               "name": "Debug",
               "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/hello_world",
               "args": [],
               "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/",
               "sourceLanguages": ["rust"]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

8. If you wanted to keep things generic and only compile a binary that matches the cargo folder name, you could use ${workspaceRootFolderName} variable substitution for the "program" key:

   ```js
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "lldb",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Debug",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/${workspaceRootFolderName}",
                "args": [],
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/",
                "sourceLanguages": ["rust"]
            }
        ]
    }
   ```

Here are some blog posts about Rust and VS Code:

- [Arch Linux](https://lustysociety.org/programming/rust_language/rust-language-linux.html)
- [On Windows](https://www.patriksvensson.se/2018/02/debugging-rust-on-windows-using-vscode)

Comment: Nice answer! It would be great if you could explain why you've added these blog posts, possibly quoting a paragraph to show their relevance.

Comment: Well, I added these posts as real life case of doing it!

Answer (score 42):

The Rust compiler produces native binaries with native debug info (symbol) information, so any native debugger will do. That means `gdb` and `lldb`, or the Windows debuggers (WinDBG or just Visual Studio) if you're using the MSVC ABI version of Rust. If you want an integrated experience, [RustDT](http://rustdt.github.io/) is the way to go (setup on Windows: [How to set up GDB for debugging Rust programs in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570021/how-to-set-up-gdb-for-debugging-rust-programs-in-windows/33570022#33570022)). Please note that you're likely to run into [How can I inspect variable values while debugging MSVC ABI Rust programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621130/how-can-i-inspect-variable-values-while-debugging-msvc-abi-rust-programs) on Windows and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33062 on a Mac.

Comment: And with `gdb 7.12`, there's now proper support, not just "works because it's compiled to native".

Answer (score 9):

For a graphical debugger, there is [gdbgui](https://gdbgui.com).  It's available for Linux, Windows and MacOS. It uses the browser as the display and to interact with the debugger.

Comment: Replying to myself, although gdbgui is useful, I have found the VS Code debugger works very well now.

Answer (score 7):

An answer that start with:

1. Install IDE xyz

... can't be a solution at all.

Go to your project folder and start `rust-gdb target/debug/your_executable`
then pick some lines where you want to break.
Hit 'run' ...

When you don't have an IDE in place (otherwise you wouldn't ask, i guess) it is the best in a Terminal/VIM users world.

Here a some hints how to use:

- https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/
- https://blog.logrocket.com/debugging-rust-apps-with-gdb/

Answer (score 5):

I have `gdb 7.11` and `rust-gdb` command seems to give more rust relevant information compared to the gdb native.
E.g. `rust-gdb` shows rust objects properly with full names, and gdb simply do not show them.
In the following example gdb would now show at all the bold parts.

```
$1 = Args = {
  inner = **ArgsOs** = {
    inner = **Args** = {
      iter = **IntoIter<std::ffi::os_str::OsString>** = {
        buf = **NonNull<std::ffi::os_str::OsString>** = {
          pointer = **NonZero<*const std::ffi::os_str::OsString>** = {
            0x7ffff6c20060
        }
      },
      phantom = **PhantomData<std::ffi::os_str::OsString>**,
      cap = 1, 
      ptr = 0x7ffff6c20060, end = 0x7ffff6c20078},
      _dont_send_or_sync_me = **PhantomData<*mut ()>**
    }
  }
}
```